# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'sentimen' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

**Help, I get an error message ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'sentimen' of non-object**

```
    public function prediksi()
        {
            $collection = array();
            $title = "Data Prediksi Sentimen";
            $testing_data = DataTesting::count();
            $klasifikasi = DataTesting::with(['data_crawling','klasifikasi'])->get();
            foreach($klasifikasi as $class){
                $prediksi = Klasifikasi::with(['sentimen'])->where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->first();
                $hasil = Hasil::where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->get();
                $aktual = Sentimen::where('id_sentimen', $class->data_crawling->id_sentimen)->first();
                $collection[] = [
                    'id_testing' => $class->id_testing,
                    'username' => $class->data_crawling->username,
                    'tweet' => $class->data_crawling->tweet,
                    'kategori' => $aktual->kategori,
                    'prediksi' => $prediksi->sentimen->kategori,
                ];
            }

            return view('visualisasi.prediksi', compact(['title','collection','testing_data','hasil']));
        }
```

[View Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvtjM.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: do you have the data in table ?? -  `sentimen`

Comment: I guess the error occurs because of this - $prediksi->sentimen->kategori. Are you sure of the key "sentimen" relationship which you have set to the "prediksi" model is not null?

Comment: you should try to do this $prediksi->sentimen->first()->kategori

Comment: @AksenP I did not find an answer there

Comment: @Hamelraj yex yes the data in the table is id_sentimen, kategori, id_crawling

Comment: @Listyawan, you're really thinking that your `error` appears at the first time in the web? It's a common error while you're trying to get unexist property of object. In your case **$prediksi** hasn't property **sentimen**.

Comment: in your foreach using `dd($prediksi->sentimen);` just check you getting data or not

Comment: @Shreeraj I tried to replace $prediksi to dd($prediksi) display results "null"

Comment: ya use if conditions before creating `$collection[] ` `if($prediksi && $prediksi->sentimen)` like

Comment: @AksenP I do not understand, please help me to improve my coding

Comment: @Listyawan, check **each** argument of **$prediksi = Klasifikasi::with(['sentimen'])->where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->first();** string.

Comment: @Hamelraj can you give an example? I do not understand

Comment: @AksenP I can't find the solution please help me

Comment: You should test if predisiki is not null or empty before working with it

Comment: how to test it?, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think if your queries and relationship is correct then use like below with **IF()** conditions

```
public function prediksi()
    {
        $collection = array();
        $title = "Data Prediksi Sentimen";
        $testing_data = DataTesting::count();
        $klasifikasi = DataTesting::with(['data_crawling','klasifikasi'])->get();
        foreach($klasifikasi as $class){
            $prediksi = Klasifikasi::with(['sentimen'])->where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->first();
            $hasil = Hasil::where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->get();
            $aktual = Sentimen::where('id_sentimen', $class->data_crawling->id_sentimen)->first();
            if($prediksi && isset($prediksi->sentimen)){
                  $collection[] = [
                'id_testing' => $class->id_testing,
                'username' => $class->data_crawling->username,
                'tweet' => $class->data_crawling->tweet,
                'kategori' => $aktual->kategori,
                'prediksi' => $prediksi->sentimen->kategori,
            ];
            }
        }

        return view('visualisasi.prediksi', compact(['title','collection','testing_data','hasil']));
    }
```

**UPDATED**

```
public function prediksi()
        {
            $collection = array();
            $title = "Data Prediksi Sentimen";
            $testing_data = DataTesting::count();
            $klasifikasi = DataTesting::with(['data_crawling','klasifikasi'])->get();
            foreach($klasifikasi as $class){
                $prediksi = Klasifikasi::with(['sentimen'])->where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->first();
                $hasil = Hasil::where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->get();
                $aktual = Sentimen::where('id_sentimen', $class->data_crawling->id_sentimen)->first();
                if($prediksi && isset($prediksi->sentimen)){
                      $collection[] = [
                    'id_testing' => $class->id_testing,
                    'username' => $class->data_crawling->username,
                    'tweet' => $class->data_crawling->tweet,
                    'kategori' => $aktual->kategori,
                    'prediksi' => $prediksi->sentimen->kategori,
                ];
                 $hasil_data[$class->id_testing][] = $hasil;
                }
            }

            return view('visualisasi.prediksi', compact(['title','collection','testing_data','hasil_data']));
        }
```

then in your view when you foreach you collection data

```
foreach($collection as $key){

  //to use hasil data
  foreach($hasil_data[$key['id_testing']] as $hasil){
     dd($hasil);

  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Listyawan you are passing `hasil` data to view. but it is insight `foreach()` check that data is correct in view

Comment: My data isn't showing up, can you help me?

Comment: @Listyawan check updated answer

Comment: my view is like this

foreach($collection as $key) endforeach

Comment: check now i used your name

Comment: thank you very much for your help but my data did not appear

Comment: show your view file

Comment: my view code https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvtjM.png

Comment: before return view check you have data - `dd($collection); dd($hasil_data);` it should work

Comment: no data is displayed, only [] is displayed